# excel vba alternate active printer

Tags: vba, excel, printing

Some people in my office print with the program Bluebeam and some with the default Adobe PDF. I have a macro to print to Bluebeam by default and a `On Error GoTo` for Adobe but it doesn't seem to work.

I've also tried `On Error Goto`...`SendKeys "^{F2}"`

```
Sub PrintPDF()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim filename As String
On Error GoTo whoa

ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, ActivePrinter:="Bluebeam PDF"
filename = Range("B2").Value
Exit Sub
whoa:
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, ActivePrinter:="Adobe PDF"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: try `Application.ActivePrinter` and / or record a macro while changing printer to PDF. Or for PDF. Use [`ExportAsFixedFormat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840291.aspx) to print to PDF. 2nd option for PDF is probably way to go. It's very reliable.

Comment: you can use `Application.ActivePrinter` to find the active printer name.